# Update query based on multiple criteria only once per row

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am fairly new to ms access (working with access 2013) and unfortunately am stuck with a problem.

I am currently working on an update query with 2 tables. In table 1 I would like to update all fields of a column with a "1" based on multiple criteria. Three different criteria exist in both tables. I only want to update the column if 2 of the criteria are exactly the same in both tables and one criteria is larger in table 2 than in table 1. However, unfortunately even if all criteria match, that does not mean that the certain case is unique. However, I just want to Update a "1" only once per unique row of table 2.

So basically, I have to questions:

1. Is the current code correct concerning the match I want to make?
2. Is there any way to tell access to only update once per unique row in table 2?

Thanks a lot for your help!

This is my current code:

```
UPDATE Table2 LEFT JOIN [Table1] ON (Table2.Criteria1 = [Table1].Criteria1) AND (Table2.[Criteria2] = [Table1].[Criteria2]) SET [Table1].Column = 1
WHERE (((Table2.[Criteria1])=[Table1].[Criteria1]) AND ((Table2.Criteria2)=[Table1].[Criteria2]) AND ((Table2.Criteria3)>=[Table1].[Criteria3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

A left join and a where on same table work as an inner join. Looking to your code seems you need a join between table1 and table2 for update table2. So the syntax and the condition should be:

```
UPDATE Table2 
    SET [Table1].Column = 1
FROM Table2 
INNER JOIN [Table1] ON Table2.Criteria1 = [Table1].Criteria1
    AND Table2.[Criteria2] = [Table1].[Criteria2]
    AND Table2.Criteria3>=[Table1].[Criteria3]
```

But if you need  an update only for a single rows the you could trying using the min(id) resulting from the matching row:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET [Table1].Column = 1 
WHERE Table1.ID  =  (
   SELECT MIN(ID) 
    FROM Table2 
    INNER JOIN [Table1] ON Table2.Criteria1 = [Table1].Criteria1 
    AND Table2.[Criteria2] = [Table1].[Criteria2] 
    AND Table2.Criteria3>=[Table1].[Criteria3] 
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That does already help quite a lot. However, i am still stuck with the problem, that i only want to Update rows in table 1 once (really only one time) per row in table 2. Unfortunately, even with my 3 criteria, the match will still not be "unique" but i have no other way to come closer than this. So is there any way i can tell access to only update one row in table 1 per row in table 2? Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you  have a primary key in the table you want to update just one row?  .. an Id, a rowid?  ...

Comment: Yes I do have an "ID" column as primary key in table 1

Comment: Hi again. First of all thanks for all your help! I tried to run the query, but unfortunately I receive a "Syntax error (missing operator) ..." message. Access marks the first "FROM"

Comment: show me the exact error message ..  anyway answer  updated ..  removed  awron ) at the second AND clause and wrong ; berfore the closinf of the subquery

Comment: Thanks! Should have noticed the wrong ; .. However, still receive the exact same Error message even after updating :/

Comment: actually using the exact same code you provided; sorry if anything stupid: UPDATE Table2 
SET [Table1].Column = 1
FROM TABLE2 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(ID) min_id
  FROM Table2 
  INNER JOIN [Table1] ON Table2.Criteria1 = [Table1].Criteria1
      AND Table2.[Criteria2] = [Table1].[Criteria2]
      AND Table2.Criteria3>=[Table1].[Criteria3]       
) t ON t.min_id = Table2.ID

Comment: So sorry, but error remains exactly the same :/ Once again using exact same code

Comment: answer  updated  change table reference ..  table1 instead of table2

Comment: answer updated  avoiding inner  join and using a where  = subquery

Comment: Thanks, code is working now. However, I think I might have been unclear of what I need. Right now the query would only update 1 row. However, my goal was to update only one row in table 1 (even if there are more than one match) per row in table 2. So more than only 1 update in total, but only 1 update per row in table 2. Dont know, whether this is even possible?

Comment: is the second time  ..  then .. for your question you should add  a clear data sample and the expected  result ..  as  tabular text  (not link to image)  ..

Comment: Thanks for your help! Will try to sort things out and then do as you proposed